# GTmetrix says Statcounter slowing website, any benefit to removing its code?

Tags: javascript, ranking, page-speed, statcounter

A few years ago, I installed Statcounter code on my website.
It's at the end of pages, just before body tag. It loads asynchronously.
When I check my pages on gtmetrix, it states that there are 2 major reasons that my pages load slowly:

1. Statcounter - takes around 1.5 seconds
2. Google adsense ads

I have Google Analytics tracking also on the pages.   I can't remove AdSense because it provides my income. Can removing statcounter help in any way toward improving page loading time and Google SEO?  I thought that because it was async, it wouldn't affect page load.

Answer (score 2):

If you already added **async** then the only thing you can do is to move it further to the footer of the page. That way there is no way it will block website content rendering.

The other thing is that all of the tools like gtmetrix are measuring total load time for the website but the DOM content (content visible for the user) may be loaded much quicker that those tools state. Of that is the case then you should not be worried as user experience will still be very good.

If your website really loads slowly for the visitor then there must be something else slowing it down and it can be due to other factors like

- TTFB - time to first byte which is due to serve me processing time, if you have any php code that takes too long that might be an issue, installing caching system may help
- other scripts preventing the page from rendering, you need to check which scripts can be moved to the footer or deferred

If you give me your website address I can check for you.

Comment: It may be simpler to change the `async` attribute to `defer`, rather than moving script tags around.